# Python regex to extract phone numbers from string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

I am very new to regex , Using python re i am looking to extract phone numbers from the following multi-line string text below :

```
 Source = """<p><strong>Kuala Lumpur</strong><strong>:</strong> +60 (0)3 2723 7900</p>
        <p><strong>Mutiara Damansara:</strong> +60 (0)3 2723 7900</p>
        <p><strong>Penang:</strong> + 60 (0)4 255 9000</p>
        <h2>Where we are </h2>
        <strong>&nbsp;Call us on:</strong>&nbsp;+6 (03) 8924 8686
        </p></div><div class="sys_two">
    <h3 class="parentSchool">General enquiries</h3><p style="FONT-SIZE: 11px">
     <strong>&nbsp;Call us on:</strong>&nbsp;+6 (03) 8924 8000
+ 60 (7) 268-6200 <br />
 Fax:<br /> 
 +60 (7) 228-6202<br /> 
Phone:</strong><strong style="color: #f00">+601-4228-8055</strong>"""
```

So when i compile the pattern , i should be able to find using

```
phone = re.findall(pattern,source,re.DOTALL)

 ['+60 (0)3 2723 7900',
  '+60 (0)3 2723 7900',
  '+ 60 (0)4 255 9000',
  '+6 (03) 8924 8686',
  '+6 (03) 8924 8000',
  '+ 60 (7) 268-6200',
  '+60 (7) 228-6202',
  '+601-4228-8055']
```

Please help me identify the right pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `re` module.

```
>>> import re
>>> Source = """<p><strong>Kuala Lumpur</strong><strong>:</strong> +60 (0)3 2723 7900</p>
        <p><strong>Mutiara Damansara:</strong> +60 (0)3 2723 7900</p>
        <p><strong>Penang:</strong> + 60 (0)4 255 9000</p>
        <h2>Where we are </h2>
        <strong>&nbsp;Call us on:</strong>&nbsp;+6 (03) 8924 8686
        </p></div><div class="sys_two">
    <h3 class="parentSchool">General enquiries</h3><p style="FONT-SIZE: 11px">
     <strong>&nbsp;Call us on:</strong>&nbsp;+6 (03) 8924 8000
+ 60 (7) 268-6200 <br />
 Fax:<br /> 
 +60 (7) 228-6202<br /> 
Phone:</strong><strong style="color: #f00">+601-4228-8055</strong>"""

>>> for i in re.findall(r'\+[-()\s\d]+?(?=\s*[+<])', Source):
    print i


+60 (0)3 2723 7900
+60 (0)3 2723 7900
+ 60 (0)4 255 9000
+6 (03) 8924 8686
+6 (03) 8924 8000
+ 60 (7) 268-6200
+60 (7) 228-6202
+601-4228-8055
>>>
```

Comment: How do i specifically avoid list elements that are less than 10 characters long OR includes alphabets using re.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. After a long try, this regex only works perfectly.

Answer (score 16):

This should find all the phone numbers in a given string

re.findall(r'+?(?[1-9][0-9 .-()]{8,}[0-9]', Source)

```
 >>> re.findall(r'[\+\(]?[1-9][0-9 .\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9]', Source)
 ['+60 (0)3 2723 7900', '+60 (0)3 2723 7900', '60 (0)4 255 9000', '+6 (03) 8924 8686', '+6 (03) 8924 8000', '60 (7) 268-6200', '+60 (7) 228-6202', '+601-4228-8055']
```

Basically, the regex lays out these rules

1. The matched string may start with + or ( symbol
2. It has to be followed by a number between 1-9
3. It has to end with a number between 0-9
4. It may contain 0-9 (space) .-() in the middle.

Comment: Amazing, this works under golang too as it seems to stick to the same basically compatible regex

Answer (score 2):

I extract the mobile number from string using the below regular expression.

```
import re

sent="this is my mobile number 9999922118"
phone = re.search(r'\b[789]\d{9}\b', sent, flags=0)
       if phone:
            phone.group(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

**pattern = "(+)?([0-9]{1,3})?( )?(([0-9]{1,3}))?( )?[(\d+((-\d+)+)]{10,15}"**

```
import re

sent = "Tampa, FL 33602 PH: 813-202-7100 FAX: 813-221-8837 phone +60 (0)3 2723 7900"
pattern = "(\+)?([0-9]{1,3})?( )?(\([0-9]{1,3}\))?( )?[(\d+((\-\d+)+)]{10,15}"
phone = re.findall(r'{}'.format(pattern), sent, flag=0)
```

This should find all the phone numbers in the string.